# Integrating over a somewhat continuous function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, continuity, boundary-value-problem

I have a function $q(t)$ that starts at $q(0)=q_0$ and needs to get to $q(1)=q_1>q_0$. I have a free parameter $z$ that I can wiggle around to control $q'(t)$. Namely, I have a function
$$q'(t)=Q(t,q(t),z)>0.$$
I know that $\forall t$, $\forall q(t)$, $\lim_{z \rightarrow -\infty}Q(t,q(t),z)=0$, and $\lim_{z \rightarrow +\infty}Q(t,q(t),z)=+\infty$. I know that $Q(t,q(t),z)$ is increasing in $z$.

1) Do I understand correctly that, if $Q(t,q(t),z)$ is continuous in $z$, I can always find $z$ such that I will hit exactly $q(1)=q_1$? Is it obvious, or some sort of a proof is in order?

2) My $Q(t,q(t),z)$ is not continuous in $z$, but the jumps, if they happen, only happen upwards, and they are not "frequent" in the sense that if there is a jump for a given $z$ at a given $t$ and $q(t)$, there is no jump for all $z$ in a small neighborhood of my $z$ for the same $t$ and $q(t)$. Can I still argue that I can always hit $q(1)=q_1$? I mean, my $Q(t,q(t),z)$ is still continuous where there are no jumps...

2.1) Would it help if I could impose that, generically, if $Q(t,q(t),z)$ has a jump at $z$ for a given $t$ and $q(t)$, $Q(t,q(t)+\varepsilon,z)$ is locally continuous at the same $z$?

3) My $Q()$ turns out to be continuously differentiable, except for the points where it jumps. That probably implies Lipschitz continuity almost everywhere, which guarantees the existence of the solution to the initial value problem if I start from $q(0)=q_0$? *upd* I can probably only care about $q\in[q_0+\infty)$, in which case my $Q()$ is bounded, and therefore continuous differentiability in $q$, which I have, is sufficient for being Lipschitz?

4) This guy (http://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/555/555_notes/continuity.pdf, p23) says that for continuity in $z$, my $Q$ should have a Lipschitz constant independent of $z$. Would boundedness and continuous differentiability suffice to get a Lipschitz constant independent of z?

Comment: Can you make it $z(t)$, or does it need to be constant, so it does not change with time?

Comment: It needs to be constant, unfortunately.

Comment: 1) is pretty simple, just monotone convergence theorem and intermediate value theorem. 2) is nasty :(

Comment: Do you know that problem has a solution? That is, does $q$ exist?

Comment: user251257: Probably: it starts from a point, it has a positive finite derivative at every point (including 1), and I can even define it well beyond the argument of 1. There's always some sort of a catch, but I don't see it right now. Thanks for the confirmation of (1)!

Comment: There is a large difference between just finding the correct value for $z$ and establishing the existence of $q$.

Comment: user251257: I understand, but all these (finite derivative at every point, etc) hold for every z. If you imagine the space of (t,q), for every z, I can plot a little arrow at every point in that space that shows what will be the next value of q. Since no arrow is "too long" (no infinite or zero derivatives), I guess that makes q() well-defined...

Comment: could you post $Q$? or is it too complicate?

Comment: user251257: It is a hazard rate of a general distribution function of a complicated argument times something like [1-F) of the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your question 2.0, here is a counterexample:

*Counterexample for 2.0*: Define $q_0=1, q_1=2$. Define $f(z)$ as follows: 
$$ f(z) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $z < \ln(4)$} \\
z& \mbox{ if $z\geq \ln(4)$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Define $Q(t,q,z) = f(z)q$. Then $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} Q(t,q,z)=\infty$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow-\infty} Q(t,q,z) = 0$, and we have only one jump discontinuity at $z=\ln(4)$. But the solution to the ODE is 
$q(t) = q(0)e^{f(z)t}$. So $q(1) = q(0)=1$ if $z < \ln(4)$ and $q(1) = e^{f(z)}\geq 4 > 2$ if $z\geq \ln(4)$.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample for question 1: let $Q = (1 + \cos^2{q})F(z)$, where $F$ is any function satisfying your conditions. It gives $q = \arctan(\sqrt{2}\tan(\sqrt{2}(Ft + c)))$, which has a limited range.

Comment: what exactly is $F$? A solution to $q'(t) = Q(t, q(t), z)$?

Comment: I tried to play with it, and it seems that as long as Q() is positive, the solution gotta be increasing... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%27%3D1%2B%28cos%28x%29%29%5E2